Update value of pandas dataframe column with leading zero where the length of the value is equal to 2
I have an example pandas data frame (df) with the following values:



Name
Label




Cat
A12


Dog
67


Mouse
20


Monkey
10.8


Parrot
V20.6



I need to update the value of the label column, which has a mix of numerical labels and integer labels but is stores as a string, to have a leading zero in certain circumstances.
What I need is where the length of the label is less than 3, there needs to be a leading zero, and where the length of the digits to the left of the decimal is less than 3, to also have this leading zero.
So, the table output I need is:



Name
Label




Cat
A12


Dog
067


Mouse
020


Monkey
010.8


Parrot
V20.6



I have tried a few different df.loc iterations for the first criteria, where length is equal to 3 but I got an error I have never gotten before and cannot find much information on: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
And I am not even sure how to approach the second criteria. Is it even possible?

Can you clarify the "where the length of the label is less than 3, there needs to be a leading zero" condition? What if you have A5 as label, should or become 0A5? Or did you mean to only consider labels that are valid numbers?

This is a god job for a regex and str.replace:
df['Label'] = df['Label'].str.replace(r'^(\d{1,2}(\.\d*)?)$', r'0\1', regex=True)

Output:
     Name  Label
0     Cat    A12
1     Dog    067
2   Mouse    020
3  Monkey  010.8
4  Parrot  V20.6

Regex demo
^         # match start of line
(         # capture
\d{1,2}   # match 1 to 2 digits
(\.\d*)?  # and an optional decimal part 
)         # end capture
$         # match end of string 

0\1       # if a match, prepend a 0


Code
# If there are integers mixed in the 'Label' column, convert to str
df['Label'] = df['Label'].astype('str')

# condition
cond = df['Label'].str.extract('(^\d+)')[0].str.len().lt(3)

# boolean masking: If the condition is True, pad with a leading '0'
df['Label'] = df['Label'].mask(cond, df['Label'].radd('0'))

df
     Name  Label
0     Cat    A12
1     Dog    067
2   Mouse    020
3  Monkey  010.8
4  Parrot  V20.6


Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Mouse', 'Monkey', 'Parrot'], 'Label': ['A12', '67', '20', '10.8', 'V20.6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


I ended up creating a data frame of the label column and splitting the values from before and after the delimiter ('.'), and then using code similar to one of the answers to replace.
cond=pd.DataFrame(df['Label'],columns=["Label","BeforeDel","AfterDel"])

cond[["BeforeDel","AfterDel"]]=cond['Label'].str.split('.', n=1, expand=True)

For labels of length 2:
cond1 =cond['BeforeDel'].str.len()==1
df['Label'] = df['Label'].mask(cond1, df['Label'].radd('00'))

For labels of length 1:
cond2 =cond['BeforeDel'].str.len()==2
df['label'] = df['label'].mask(cond2, df['label'].radd('0'))

The regex info is interesting and I will look into more of it, but didn't quite work for the labels of 1 digit. Using the ==1 and ==2 accounts also for values of 1 digits, which wasn't in the example data but was something I needed.
